# C++ RTTI without libstdc++. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, linux, rtti, libstdc++, abi

I want investigate how is it possible to link C++ program without libstdc++, but with support of rtti. I tried compile it in the way described below. Any necessary but absent  symbol I can define like function strcmp in the example, but is it possible to define typeinfo symbols without explicit mangle/demangle magic? And if possible how?

`cd /tmp && cat << 'eof' >rtti.cpp && g++  -nodefaultlibs -lc rtti.cpp`

```
extern "C" int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) { return 0; };
#include "typeinfo"

int main(){
    return typeid(int) == typeid(char);
}
```

Linker says:

/tmp/cc6rBAef.o: In function `main':

```
rtti.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for char'
rtti.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `typeinfo for int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, how can I define 'typeinfo of char'(_ZTIc@@CXXABI_1.3) in source file using g++ or clang++?

PS. Don't ask me why do I need it. Just a curiosity.

Comment: I don't know if the option '-nostartfiles' helps in this case.

Comment: It doesn't matter used it or not. The question is about elf symbols. Imagine i used "g++ ./ti.cc  -nodefaultlibs -lc" if you like.

Comment: It says it can't find the `_start` function. Maybe using that option it wil not try to find it, but one that you provide in the link file that you should create.

Comment: Shouldn't you include `<typeinfo>` instead of `"typeinfo"`?

Comment: Yes I should, but not must. Compiler will find proper header anyway. [proof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC6)

Comment: @SpoonwalkerHighwater, that is not proof, it just means it happens to work for GCC, but is not gauarnteed by the standard. The standard has a non-normative note that says: "Although an implementation may provide a mechanism for making arbitrary source files available to the `< >` search, in general programmers should use the `< >` form for headers provided with the implementation, and the `" "` form for sources outside the control of the implementation."

Comment: You can link to `libsupc++` instead of `libstdc++`, it contains the minimum run-time pieces needed for RTTI and exception handling, without all the other standard library stuff in `libstdc++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [gcc community](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-06/msg00095.html) for hint.

The answer is:

"gcc use some magic to substitute destructor of __fundamental_type_info to a set of typeinfo symbols"

Substitution code is placed in file: gcc-4.7.2/gcc/cp/rtti.c,  `void emit_support_tinfos(void);`

rtti.cc:

```
#include <typeinfo>
namespace __cxxabiv1 {
class __fundamental_type_info:public std::type_info{
public:
     explicit __fundamental_type_info(const char* __n) : std::type_info(_n) { } 
     virtual ~__fundamental_type_info(){}; 
};
}
int main(){
    return typeid(int) == typeid(char);
}
```

All fundamental typeinfos are inserted into object file during compilation.

`$g++ -c ./rtti.cc;readelf -sW ./rtti.o |c++filt|grep typeinfo|wc -l`

`$153`

So the question is answered.

Answer (score 4):

Since the symbols needed for RTTI seem to be in the `libstdc++` library, you cannot do completely without it. Note that I found this by running

```
readelf -Ws `g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.so` | awk '{print $8}' | c++filt | grep 'typeinfo for'
```

What you *can* do, however, is statically link with `libstdc++`:

```
g++ -static-libstdc++ rtti.cpp
```

In this way, you won't have any dynamic dependencies on `libstdc++` and only the symbols you actually need are pulled in to your executable. (Well, all symbols from the object file that contains the needed symbols, `fundamental_type_info.o` in you example, I suppose.)

Comment: You're referencing a blog post from 2005. Nowadays, you can pass the `-static-libstdc++` option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also found fundamental_type_info.o. But the file gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/fundamental_type_info.cc is empty. It seems that fundamental types are generated in file gcc-4.8.0/gcc/cp/rtti.c, but i'm not sure. I keep trying.

Comment: @SpoonwalkerHighwater: Well, in the end it doesn't really matter which `.o` file contains these symbols since the correct one will be pulled in automatically when you link statically. Or are you actually trying to implement RTTI by yourself? In that case, take a look at the relevant section of the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#rtti).

Comment: Really I want to know how compiler define fundamental_type_info. I read Itanium ABI, but it give no keys to understand how the variables are implemented. Typeinfo for user classes is generated by g++, but typeinfo of fundamental types is located in libstdc++. As far as libstdc++ was compiled and linked as an ordinary lib there are exists a way to generate typeinfo for fundamental types in users lib. I want to find it.

Comment: @SpoonwalkerHighwater: I once created an RTTI implementation myself and the *only* documentation I used was the ABI I linked to so all required "keys" should be there. If you want, I could post my implementation somewhere.

Comment: If you can public your implementation it would be very interesting. And i suppose not for me only. So please post it and thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do without libstdc++, you can link to libsupc++ instead.